# if $\vec{u}$ is orthogonal to $\nabla f(\vec{x})$ $\forall $ $\vec{x}$ , then why $\vec{u} \equiv \vec{0} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Original question (Apostol 12.23):

What can you conclude about $f$ if $f'(\vec{x};\vec{u})=0$ for a fixed direction $\vec{u}$ and every $\vec{x}$ in open ball $B(\vec{c})$?

edit: $f'(\vec{x};\vec{u})=0$ is the directional derivative at $\vec{x} $
along $\vec{u}$

Comment: These are two separate questions.

Comment: can you answer the second one?

Comment: What do you think it means?

Comment: I have no idea what it means

Comment: What values do you think $f$ will take on the part of the line $x+tu$ that intersects the ball?

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to use the definition of the directional derivative?

Comment: No, I'm asking you what conclusion can you draw from $\phi'(t) = 0$ where $\phi(t) = f(x+tu)$???

Comment: I see... I need to use the mean value theorem

Comment: No, first you need to use your intuition.

Comment: Remember that $\phi$ (as copper hat has defined) is just an ordinary function from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, If a real-valued function of a real variable has zero derivative *everywhere* in an interval, what does that tell you about the function?